# {Tricky Excel} How can I plot a time-time vs values chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have 2 columns:
Column A with data: time - time (example: 08:00:00-15:59:59)
Column B with data: Values from 1 to 20.

I want to see between what hours are values from column B the greatest.

Is it possible to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this?

[image]

Formulae are:

- `c2`: `=LEFT($A2,8)`
- `d2`: `=MID($A2,10,99)`
- `e2`: `=D2-C2`
- `f2`: `=HOUR(E2)`
- `g2`: `=MIN(B2,F2)`